# Python Parsing XML - if element == "value" do x

Tags: python, xml

sorry if title isn't that clear, I'm currently parsing a xml file that has lots of nested tags,  for example it goes:

```
<Artifacts>
 <Artifact name="1">
  <Fragments>
   <hits>
    <hit sequence="1">
     <Fragment name="1">Data</Fragment>
     <Fragment name="2">Data</Fragment>
    </hit>
   </hits>
  </Fragments>
 </Artifact>
 <Artifact name="2">
```

(Making layout a bit clearer sorry)
and so on. The pain I'm currently having is to be able to get only the data we need. From the example above we require everything under Artifact name=1, and to pull out the fragment name of "1" along with Data. The outcome aimed for would be something like:

Artifact = "1", Fragment Name = "1", Fragment Data = "Data".

At present I just can't seem to get to grips with it, I've done similar with PHP without issues but this is required to be done in python really.

So bit long winded sorry, but does anyone have any ideas how to specify to only grab the data from the artifacts named 1,3,5 for example and ignore everything else? All I can seem to do is grab it from everything in the file (which slows it down and then requires further processing)

thanks.

Comment: Have you heard about XPath ? Install [lxml](http://lxml.de/xpathxslt.html#the-xpath-method] and search elements matching `"/Artifacts/Artifact[@name = '1' or @name = '3' or @name = '5']"`, for instance.

Comment: @LaurentLAPORTE, or `[@name = ('1', '3', '5')]`; in XPath, `=` actually looks for set intersection.

Comment: @Charles Duffy: Which version of XPath? I have never eared about that, it must be a recent change. But `lxml` don’t like it: `tree.xpath("/Artifacts/Artifact[@name = ('1', '3', '5')]")` raises `lxml.etree.XPathEvalError: Invalid expression`.

Comment: Argh. I don't have a good handle on what was introduced when -- much of my experience with XPath comes from it being a subset of XQuery (in which my familiarity is mostly with 3.0).

Answer (score 1):

With minidom:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

xmlstr = '''
<Artifacts>
<Artifact name="1">
<Fragments>
<Fragment name="1">Data</Fragment>
</Fragments>
</Artifact>
<Artifact name="2">
</Artifact>
</Artifacts>
'''


def with_children(tag):
    if tag.localName: # if not, it's text node
        print tag.localName,
        if tag.hasAttributes():
            for item in tag.attributes.items():
                print "%s=%s" % item,

        for child in tag.childNodes:
            with_children(child)

    else:
        s = tag.nodeValue.strip()
        print "data=%s" % s if s else "",

xml = minidom.parseString(xmlstr)
tags = xml.getElementsByTagName('Artifact')
tag = [t for t in tags if t.attributes['name'].value == '1'][0]
with_children(tag)
```

Comment: That's great thanks :) I was using minidom before so this fits in more with what I'm used to (a bit ) and have been trying. Will try and tweak this to fir more of my needs as the final outcome is to change the format of the XML file to allow import into another system.

Is there a way of doing the search then keeping the XML format to be able to loop through it to grab the data out thats required? 

only grab out '<Fragment name="1">Data</Fragment>'as this will later need to be changed to an xml format a bit like "<hash>Data</hash>" etc?

Comment: There is minidom.getDOMImplementation to create documents and nodes.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple example using `lxml`:

```
from lxml import etree

content = '''\
<Artifacts>
  <Artifact name="1">
    <Fragments>
      <Fragment name="1">Data</Fragment>
    </Fragments>
  </Artifact>
  <Artifact name="2">
    <Fragments>
      <Fragment name="2">Data2</Fragment>
    </Fragments>
  </Artifact>
  <Artifact name="3">
    <Fragments>
      <Fragment name="3">Data3</Fragment>
    </Fragments>
  </Artifact>
</Artifacts>
'''

tree = etree.XML(content)

elts = tree.xpath("/Artifacts/Artifact[@name = '1' or @name = '3' or @name = '5']")

for elt in elts:
    etree.dump(elt)
```

You'll get:

```
<Artifact name="1">
    <Fragments>
      <Fragment name="1">Data</Fragment>
    </Fragments>
  </Artifact>

<Artifact name="3">
    <Fragments>
      <Fragment name="3">Data3</Fragment>
    </Fragments>
  </Artifact>
```

If you want to extract each Fragment:

```
artifacts = tree.xpath("/Artifacts/Artifact[@name = '1' or @name = '3' or @name = '5']")

fmt = 'Artifact = "{art_name}",' \
      'Fragment Name = "{frag_name}",' \
      'Fragment Data = "{data}".'
for artifact in artifacts:
    for fragments in artifact.iter("Fragments"):
        for fragment in fragments.iter("Fragment"):
            print(fmt.format(art_name=artifact.get("name"),
                             frag_name=fragment.get("name"),
                             data=fragment.text))
```

You'll get:

```
Artifact = "1", Fragment Name = "1", Fragment Data = "Data".
Artifact = "3", Fragment Name = "3", Fragment Data = "Data3".
```